# knockout object value changes but ui remains the same

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a drop down list that is bound to a `SelectedFormat` value. The lists options are populated from external source on load and matches the view models `data.Format` object base on id.

Take a look at the [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QrvJN/8/)

Can anyone tell me why the model updates but the UI is not updating with the correct `Format.Name`

Thanks.

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="text:data.Format.Name"></div>
<select data-bind="
    options:Controls,
    optionsText: 'Name',
    value: data.SelectedFormat"></select>
```

Model:

```
var jsonData = {
    Id: "abc-123",
    Name: "Chicken Cheese",
    Format: {
        Id: 2,
        Name: 'Medium',
        Other: 'Bar'
    }
};

var self = this;
self = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
self.SelectedFormat = ko.observable(
    //return the first match based on id
    $.grep(vm.Controls,function(item){            
        return item.Id === self.Format.Id();
    })[0]
);

//when changed update the actual object that will be sent back to server 
self.SelectedFormat.subscribe(function (d) {
    this.Format = d;        
},self);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you have `Format` and `SelectedFormat`. The former isn't an observable and so can't trigger updates. You have to use `SelectedFormat` instead.

```
<div data-bind="text:data.SelectedFormat().Name"></div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/QrvJN/9/

Comment: looking at answers you seem like a knockout pro. Is there a better way to set SelectedFormat initially?

Comment: Knockout includes `ko.utils.arrayFirst` which would be a little more direct: `ko.utils.arrayFirst(vm.Controls,function(item){            
        return item.Id === self.Format.Id();
    })`

Comment: Also I usually don't use the "mapping" tool, and instead do any mapping manually. But if you do want to use the mapping tool, you can specify how certain parts are mapped. It would then be possible to map `Format` using the above code, and therefore not have two copies of it in your view model.

Comment: format is property buried 3 layers deep inside an array of arrays. The app i am working on has many components to it and some of the objects(like the format) have 20 plus properties and they are not all finalized. I have 5 template views displaying all the properties at different times an then there is the add models(which are not in the mapping). Anything i can do to simplify things is good, I use mapping options where I can and at one point had format mapping to a new observable but for some unknown reason canned it.